# How to add multiple buttons on the top navigation of iOS App

Tags: ios, rubymotion

I am creating a simple app and would like multiple buttons on top bar. I've added one button which would add new items but I want other buttons there as well for the user to go to different screens. This is how it looks now.

[image]

Is there a way to add other buttons on the bar? If so, how? Or is it common to have a tab bar for this functionality? Such as this

[image]

Comment: you can, you can use navigation bar as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can have multiple buttons on your navigation bar. You can either add them on the right side or left side of your bar. To do that, you need to create multiple bar buttons and add them as an array. Something like this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *actionBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:nil];

UIBarButtonItem *addBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:nil];

UIBarButtonItem *bookmarksBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemBookmarks target:self action:nil];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = @[actionBtn, addBtn, bookmarksBtn]; //Considering that you want to have three buttons on the right side.
```

Answer (score 0):

you can put two buttons on navigation bar one in left and other in right

see screen shot i have done

[image]

Comment: yes, I am aware of putting buttons on right and left. My question is can I put, say, three buttons on the right instead of one?